# how to add pagination link in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework, but usual, I have done pagination under codeigniter but now I am facing some issue, that I could not click the link because of baseurl, I have siblink that is (base_url ().'franchise/loginconfirm#parentHorizontalTab3/') parentHorizontalTab3 is a siblink, when I use this Sublink I could not click pagination link its not working, how can i create pagination with is url? please help me. My code is below

```
    $config['base_url']         = base_url().'franchise/loginconfirm#parentHorizontalTab3/';
    $config['total_rows']       = $this->ui_franchise_model->sel_adslist_product_count();   
    $offset                 = $this->uri->segment(3,0);
    $config['suffix']          = '#' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
    $config['per_page']         = 4;
    $config['uri_segment']  = '3';
    $config['num_links']        = 3;        
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page_links']     = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `$config['uri_segment']  = 3;` instead of `$config['uri_segment']  = '3';`

Hope it will work

Comment: thanks for your reply, but its not working, again facing same issue

Comment: problem is that url segment not geting after # simbole